# Como hacer consulta Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una tabla llamada mensaje que tiene `para_usuario_id` y `de_usuario_id`, deseo obtener en la condición los mensajes recibidos y enviados por el mismo usuario.

La variable `$id` recibe el id de la persona con quien desea chat, y en  `\auth()->user()->id`, el id de la persona que esta enviando el mensaje.

Lo que deseo es obtener ambos mensajes de ida y vuelta.

```php
$mensage = Mensaje::where("para_usuario_id", $id)
    ->whereOr("de_usuario_id", \auth()->user()->id)
    ->whereOr("para_usuario_id", $id)
    ->whereOr("de_usuario_id",  \auth()->user()->id)
    ->paginate(50);
```

Comment: Y qué es lo que obtienes con esa query?

Comment: Solo me devuelve los enviados, pero no enviados y recibidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereOr`? Siempre he visto que el método se llama `orWhere`. Dejando eso de lado, la consulta es simple. Tienes que agrupar las condiciones.

```sql
SELECT * FROM mensajes
WHERE (
    para_usuario_id = @id1 AND de_usuario_id = @id2
) OR (
    para_usuario_id = @id2 AND de_usuario_id = @id1
)
```

Eso usando el query builder de Laravel ser vería así:

```php
Mensaje::query()
    ->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('para_usuario_id', $id)
              ->where('de_usuario_id', \auth()->id());
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('para_usuario_id', \auth()->id())
              ->where('de_usuario_id', $id);
    })
    ->get();
```

`auth()->id()` es lo mismo que `auth()->user()->id`.